# Getting the second highest value by employee

Tags: sql

I have a table called `Agent_Summary`, and the columns in the table I am using are `AgentName`, `ManagerName`, `DepartmentName`, and `CallDate`.

The `CallDate` shows the date in which the agent answered a phone call, which occurs multiple times in the day if the agent worked.

**What I am trying to do** is as followings:

1. Get the last day and the second last day that each agent worked using `CallDate`.
2. Get the last day and the second last day that each manager worked using `CallDate`.
3. Return the last day and the second last day group by agent name, but only those agents who worked in the last day that their managers worked.

To avoid any confusion, here is the example:

```
Name    | Last Day | Second Last Day

Manager | 3-11-2019 | 3-10-2019  
AgentA  | 3-11-2019 | 3-10-2019  
AgentB  | 3-11-2019 | 3-9-2019  
AgentC  | 3-10-2019 | 3-9-2019  
AgentD  | 3-11-2019 | 3-8-2019
```

let's say `Agent_Summary` table looks like above. Then I want the query to return

```
AgentA  | 3-11-2019 | 3-10-2019  
AgentB  | 3-11-2019 | 3-9-2019   
AgentD  | 3-11-2019 | 3-8-2019
```

Can anybody help me with this? Thank you for your time in advance.